# What does "make something a hit" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "make something a hit" mean "make something a success" or "make something canceled" here?
(I used this link https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+hit)

> Transparent, an Emmy winner, was watched by 1.49 million people between Sept 21. and May 2 according to data cited by Variety. Even Man in the High Castle -- Amazon Prime Video's highest-rated show at the time (the 2016 TV season) -- only lured in 3.44 million viewers during the entire TV season.
>
> Those numbers would **make High Castle a hit** by cable standards, and canceled if it aired on a network. Transparent wouldn't have made a second week on a network, and it would be an iffy proposition on any major channel.
>
> Source:https://www.ibtimes.com/apple-making-multi-billion-dollar-mistake-2741084

Answer (score 1):

High ratings (called "numbers" in your second paragraph) make a show a **hit** (that is, they indicate a show is very popular).

Your sentence is saying that one-and-a-half million viewers mean a show is a "hit" on cable, but that same number would be a failure as a network show. This implies more people watch network shows than cable shows.

I'm not an expert in television viewership numbers, but I can contrive an example. Let's say the average number of viewers of a network show is five million, and the average number of viewers of a cable show is one million.

If you and I create a new show that gets 1.5 million viewers, would that be a success, or a failure? The answer depends on whether the show is being aired on cable or on regular network television. On cable, our show would be considered a hit (it has 50% more viewers than the average show), but on network television, that same viewership number would be considered very low, and thus the show would be regarded as a failure and it would likely be cancelled (in other words, taken off the air at the end of the season).